# Javascript - Jquery .live()

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery

I have a deeply-nested form where levels of elements get added and removed dynamically by the user (using the [Jquery-deep branch](https://github.com/ryanb/complex-form-examples/tree/unobtrusive-jquery-deep) in Ryan Bates' Complex Forms Examples). I have attached to each of these elements some Javascript functions and I am having trouble getting them to stay `.live()` when new elements are added.

I'm trying to get this to work with James Padolsey's [Autoresize](http://james.padolsey.com/javascript/jquery-plugin-autoresize/):

```
# This code functions but only for existing elements. How to make it .live()?
<%= javascript_include_tag "autoresize.jquery.min" %>
<script type="text/javascript">
$('#notes, textarea, .optionBox').autoResize({
    onResize : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
    },
    // After resize:
    animateCallback : function() {
        $(this).css({opacity:1});
    },
    animateDuration : 150,
    extraSpace : 0,
    limit : 210
  });
</script>
```

I've tried inserting the .live() function a few ways but they haven't worked. How can I get it to function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at the more preferred method, `delegate`

Comment: How would I implement delegate, Aaron?

Comment: you give it a context node so that it will work with current or future nodes. Make sure the context node is not replaced by your callback

Comment: Aaron, I got delegate working with `$("body").delegate('#notes, textarea, .optionBox', "click", function(){`... but the page is very slow - it appears to be eating up processor usage to the point where typing is delayed in text_areas! How on earth can this be sped up?

Comment: Can you get the context any closer to the elements you want to target? James Padolsey's a good coder so I doubt his code is inefficient. You could try dropping him an email or tweeting him maybe. It's hard to know if you're doing anything else that would slow it down without seeing your implementation though. Try putting your code on jsfiddle

Answer (score 1):

Check out plugin [livequery](http://brandonaaron.net/code/livequery/docs)

Example of usage

```
$('textarea').livequery(function(){

        if ($(this).attr("class") != "resized"){
            $(this).attr("class","resized");

            $(this).autoResize({
            // On resize:
            onResize : function() {
                $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
            },
            // After resize:
            animateCallback : function() {
                $(this).css({opacity:1});
            },
            // Quite slow animation:
            animateDuration : 300,
            // More extra space:
            extraSpace : 40
            });


        }

    });
```

Comment: How is livequery different from JQuery's .live()? Will .live() on its own not work for this?

Comment: I updated example. I just checked - it works fine. 

It's just another way to binding events etc. For example, you don't need to define event type - the code will run for each element after updating of page

"Live Query utilizes the power of jQuery selectors by binding events or firing callbacks for matched elements auto-magically, even after the page has been loaded and the DOM updated"

Comment: Another way is adding .autoResize after updating of DOM elements. For example you can add class "resizable" to already resizable elements. $("a").live("click",function(){ $("textarea[class!=resizable]").autoResize(...) }) and in animate callback just add $(this).attr("class","resizable")

Comment: Livequery is eating up my processor so much the form can't handle typing any more!

Comment: Got it. So, I think the best way in your case is after adding a new textarea you should call .autoResize() for the last added textarea...

Answer (score 0):

you can use live function in fallowing way

```
$('#notes, textarea, .optionBox').live('click',autoResize({
onResize : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
},
// After resize:
animateCallback : function() {
    $(this).css({opacity:1});
},
animateDuration : 150,
extraSpace : 0,
limit : 210   }););
```

event can be onclick,onfocus...etc.
even you can attach the handler and call autoResize through that handler.

Comment: Standard .live() usage doesn't work here because autoResize doesn't take an event in that way - look at the code I provided.

Comment: you can attach a eventHandler and put the resize code in to that handler...i think this should work.

Comment: Vivek - I'm sorry, I'm not very familiar with javascript in general - can you show me what I would have to do in the code itself?

Comment: Yes, no luck. See, from my original code - the function autoResize relies on its own .js file and we don't pass it any event (such as 'click'). That's why I think it isn't working.

Answer (score 0):

same issue like yours, working with event 'click' but required extra mouse click on textarea, with event 'focus' working excellent but text dissapiar after living textarea(for my case)

```
            $('textarea').live('click', function() {
                        $(this).autoResize({
                            // On resize:
                            onResize : function() {
                                $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
                            },
                            // After resize:
                            animateCallback : function() {
                                $(this).css({opacity:1});
                            },
                            // Quite slow animation:
                            animateDuration : 300,
                            // More extra space:
                            extraSpace : 10
                        });

                });
```

Answer (score 0):

my working solution :

```
                   $('textarea').live('focus blur', function(event) {
                        if (event.type == 'focus') {
                            $(this).autoResize({
                                // On resize:
                                onResize : function() {
                                    $(this).css({opacity:0.8});
                                },
                                // After resize:
                                animateCallback : function() {
                                    $(this).css({opacity:1});
                                },
                                // Quite slow animation:
                                animateDuration : 300,
                                // More extra space:
                                extraSpace : 10
                            });
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            $(this).die();
                        }
                });
```

Answer (score 0):

better solution for this case:
use this plugin [link text](http://www.unwrongest.com/projects/elastic/)
then code is:

```
 $('textarea').live('focus', function() {
    $(this).elastic();
 });
```